# Piping output of a failed command in windows command prompt (cmd.exe)

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm trying to redirect stderr to stdout and then use `tee` to both show it on sceen and dump to a file.

When running a command with a typo (to which cmd reacts with `'CommandNameWithATypo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`) I expect this error message to be shown on screen and also written to the file specified in the `tee` command. However, running this:

```
CommandNameWithATypo 2>&1 | tee test.txt
```

I get no output on screen nor to a file (no file is created), as if piping never happened. Is this intended to be like this? May there be a workaround?

Comment: you *do*  have `tee` installed, don't you?

Comment: @Stephan yes, and it does work for cases like `echo blabla | tee file.txt`

Comment: try `( CommandNameWithATypo 2>&1 ) | tee test.txt` to bind `2>&1` to the left side of the pipe

Comment: @Stephan Yes, that works! Thanks a lot. Do you know what was exactly was happening inside the interpreter when not using parenthesis? P.S. If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as the best one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is, that "cmd knows best where to put redirection" /for prove, write a batch file with `>nul echo hello` (don't turn `echo off`), run it and watch the output. You can force it to bind redirection to the intended part of the code with a code block:

```
( CommandNameWithATypo 2>&1 ) | tee test.txt
```

(sorry for "you *do* have tee installed, don't you?", but without `tee`, you get exactly what you described: nothing. Try `wrongCommand 2>&1 | notTee file.txt`)

Comment: PS: if you really want to crawl through it, start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/2152082). Be warned: this is "the land of headache"